# SSRS running total on percentage, show based on only every 10th value

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS report I have a field with percentage values from which I have calculated cumulative running total. On the third field user wants to see only values which are closest to every ten value and blank out everything else. 
So in the example we show 8 as cumulative value, as it is closest to 10. For the second value we choose 20 as it is closest value to 20. For the third we take 32, closest to 30. then 40, 52 , 62, 73, 79, 91

```
%   cumulative val   showed values
3         3              
5         8               8
6        14  
3        17  
2        19 
1        20              20
4        24
3        27
5        32              32  
7        39
1        40              40
2        42
2        44
3        47
5        52              52   
2        54
3        57
1        58
4        62              62
3        65
1        66
7        73              73
2        75
1        76
3        79              79
4        83
2        85
3        88
1        89
2        91              91
```

I have tried to use the solution with different set of records and that's what I can see

[Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb9WN.png)

Comment: This is one of those requirements that is best solved outside of the report builder. In your select query or in code. I would just edit my dataset layout to have an extra column which you use to determine if it should be displayed.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve it by using custom code, if you can add the row number to your dataset let me know i'll try to prove if my approach can help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes adding row number is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I find questions like this in [reporting-services](/questions/tagged/reporting-services) tag I think about the possibilities users could have if there were something like a `NEXT()` function, contrary to the `PREVIOUS()` supported function.

Okay, I vented.

---

I recreated the table you posted in the question and added row number to the dataset.

Go to `Report` menu / `Report Properties` / `Code` tab, in the text area put the following code.

```
Dim running_current as Integer = 0
Dim flag as Integer = 0
Public Function Visible(ByVal a as Integer,ByVal b as Integer) As String
    running_current = running_current + a
    Dim running_next as Integer = running_current + b

    Dim a_f as Integer = CInt(Math.ceiling(running_current / 10.0)) * 10
    Dim b_f as Integer = CInt(Math.ceiling(running_next / 10.0)) * 10

    if flag = 1 Then
        flag = 0
        return "true"
    End If
        
    If a_f = b_f Then
        return "false"
    Else 
        IF Closest(running_current,running_next) = "false" Then
            flag = 1
            return "false"
        End If
        return "true"
    End if
End Function
        
Public Function Closest(ByVal a as Integer, ByVal b as Integer) as String
    Dim target as Integer = CInt(Math.ceiling(a / 10.0)) * 10
    IF Math.abs(a-target)>= Math.abs(b-target) Then
        return "false"
    Else
        return "true"
    End IF
End Function
```

This function compares every value with the next based on the row number in order to determine if it must be showed or not. If the value must be showed it returns `true`, otherwise `false` string is returned.

You have to pass the value to the function and the next to it, based on the row number. The `lookup()` function plus row number give us a similar behaviour to a `NEXT()` function.

```
=IIf(
Code.Visible(Fields!Value.Value,
Lookup(Fields!RowNumber.Value+1,Fields!RowNumber.Value,Fields!Value.Value,"DataSet11")),
ReportItems!Textbox169.Value,
Nothing
)
```

For the first row it will pass `3` and `5` to determine if `3` must be showed, then 5 and 6 to determine if the cumulative value must be showed, and so on.

I've created another column as your example, and used the above expression. It says if the function Code.Visible function returns true show the Textbox169 (cumulative value column) otherwise show `Nothing`.

[image]

For Running column I've used the typical running value expression:

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Value.Value,Sum,"DataSet11")
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check if it worked for me. Really apreciate your help.